# typescript issue with discriminated unions and types

Tags: typescript, functional-programming, zod

I am trying to implement discriminated unions with typescript and am running into an issue in one of my conditions.

Here is the current code:

```
import { z, ZodError } from 'zod';

let parsedUser = z.object({
    password: z.string().min(1).max(8),
    firstName: z.string().min(1).max(8),
    lastName: z.string().min(1).max(8)
});

type User = {
    password: string,
    firstName: string,
    lastName: string
}

type UserParserOutcome =
    ZodError | User;

export const userParser = (user: unknown): UserParserOutcome => {
    let result = parsedUser.safeParse(user);

    if (!result.success)
        return result.***error***;
    else
        return result.data as User;
};
```

I created a UserParserOutcome that should return one of two types, ZodError or User and according to zod documentation it should return either an error property or a data property.

[image]

The else condition seems fine but WebStorm seems to mark the "return result.error" line as an error.  When I mouseover the line, I am getting the following error:

[image]

What am I missing here?  The documentation makes sense but there seems to be an issue with the error property.

Comment: I can't reproduce this error. https://tsplay.dev/WP19Kw Have you posted the correct code here in your example? Are you using the latest version of zod?

Comment: This is the code.  Yes, I am using the latest version of zod.

Comment: https://zod.dev/?id=requirements make sure you have TS4.5+ and enable `strict`